# How to append two values to a dictionary at once in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I don't think the title really explains it, but here's the problem.

My code is this (Python 2.7):

```
    Dict = {}
    for i in range(0, 6):
        for j in range(0, 7):
            Dict[i][j] = 0;
    return Dict;
```

But I always get KeyError: 0.

Comment: When you access `Dict[i]` the item does not magically come into existence (that is what `defaultdict` is for). Because `Dict[i]` refers to an element not in the dictionary, you get a `KeyError` (i.e. "*this item is not in here*").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, set one at a time:

```
mydict = {}
for i in range(0, 6):
    mydict[i] = {}

    for j in range(0, 7):
        mydict[i][j] = 0

return mydict
```

That is, if you want something like this:

```
{
    0:{
        0: 0,
        // ...
    },
    // ...
}
```

The problem you were running into is that you were trying to set an item of an item, before defining what the i-th item was.

Answer (score 0):

Use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = defaultdict(dict)

for i in range(0, 6):
    for j in range(0, 7):
        a[i][j] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you have to explicitly define each index in a dictionary. You can have them auto created for you like this

```
import collections
auto_dict = lambda: collections.defaultdict(auto_dict)

my_dict = auto_dict()
my_dict['lvl1']['lvl2'] = 1
print my_dict['lvl1']['lvl2']
# 1
```